# Building an iOS chat app on Windows using React

Tags: ios, react-native

I am new to mobile development. I want to build an iOS chat app. I have a Windows machine and my plan is to code using React or React Native and test the app on Android. I'll then give the code to my friend who has a Mac and he will build the code for iOS. Is this a reasonable path forward? Should I use React or React Native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable path, but you should keep in mind that you'll need to work on your friend's mac a little bit too cause there are always differences. For example, some package configuration or behavior might differ, so you'll have do deal with few fixes.

React Native is used for mobile apps development, React (Reactjs) is for web development.